# JSSOR - How to reverse the Stone Transition Slide direction

Tags: jssor

I am trying to use the Stone Transition, but I want the image to slide in from the right to the left, the only transition available is "Slide Right" from the left to right.

It seems to me that most people, being right handed, will tend to click a right arrow to move forward. Likewise it seems more intuitive for an auto-slide to flow in the same direction.

I looked through the JS file, but couldn't make heads nor tails. I UnMinified it, but still no further headway.

Maybe I am missing it, but how can I reverse the direction of the Stone Transition - Slide Right?

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured it out.

So the difference in this case, is that you don't use the preset transitions, but instead under the Slider Options, select the "InQuad" dropdown under "Ease". Play around with your Idle & Duration and you are good to go.

Hope this helps someone else